# Get name / alias of column in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, alias

I am defining a column object like this:

```py
column = F.col('foo').alias('bar')
```

I know I can get the full expression using `str(column)`,
but how can I get the column's alias only?

In the example, I'm looking for a function `get_column_name` where `get_column_name(column)` returns the string `bar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is through regular expressions:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
column = col('foo').alias('bar')
print(column)
#Column<foo AS `bar`>

import re
print(re.findall("(?<=AS `)\w+(?=`>$)", str(column)))[0]
#'bar'
```

Comment: I had the same thought as you, but I was hoping for a way to do this via the spark API directly. But this will work for now, thanks a lot!

Comment: @surjikal if you had the dataframe you could get the columns after the transformation: something like `df.select(column).columns`

Comment: I'm doing this for some kind of generic module, where I'm working with columns that aren't bound to a dataframe.

Comment: I have similar problem where I get column object that may or may not have an alias 
OR a string containing column name and I need to return string "table_alias.column_name" (where table_alias I add to that column name, its not taken from that column object). Its a bummer that column object dont have property returning qualified name

Comment: I want w/e alias was given last, since that's what the resulting column would be named. I tweaked it to ``re.findall(r"(?<=AS `)\w+(?<!`)", str(column))[-1]``

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, we could use a wrapper function to tweak the behavior of `Column.alias` and `Column.name` methods to store the *alias only* in an `AS` attribute:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Column, SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode, array, struct, lit
SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

def alias_wrapper(self, *alias, **kwargs):
    renamed_col = Column._alias(self, *alias, **kwargs)
    renamed_col.AS = alias[0] if len(alias) == 1 else alias
    return renamed_col

Column._alias, Column.alias, Column.name, Column.AS = Column.alias, alias_wrapper, alias_wrapper, None
```

which then guarantees:

```py
assert(col("foo").alias("bar").AS == "bar")
# `name` should act like `alias`
assert(col("foo").name("bar").AS == "bar")
# column without alias should have None in `AS`
assert(col("foo").AS is None)
# multialias should be handled
assert(explode(array(struct(lit(1), lit("a")))).alias("foo", "bar").AS == ("foo", "bar"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function works well with cases like:

- several aliases
- aliases containing several words
- intentional backticks in aliases

```py
def get_col_name(col):
    if str(col)[-3] != '`':
        return str(col).split("'")[-2].split(" AS ")[-1]
    return str(col).replace('``', '`').split(" AS `")[-1].split("`'")[-2]
```

Testing:

`````py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols = [
    F.col('foo'),
    F.col('foo').alias('bar'),
    F.col('foo').alias('bar').alias('baz'),
    F.col('foo').alias('foo bar'),
    F.col('foo').alias('foo AS bar'),
    F.col('foo').alias('foo AS bar').alias('bar AS baz'),
    F.col('foo').alias('foo AS bar').alias('baz'),
    F.col('foo').alias('foo AS bar').alias('````bar AS baz````'),
]

for c in cols:
    print(get_col_name(c))

# foo
# bar
# baz
# foo bar
# foo AS bar
# bar AS baz
# baz
# ````bar AS baz````
`````

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not needed. For PySpark 3.x it looks like backticks were replaced with quotes, so this might not work out of the box on earlier spark versions, but should be easy enough to modify.

*Note: requires  Python 3.9+*

```py
from pyspark.sql import Column

def get_column_name(col: Column) -> str:
    """
    PySpark doesn't allow you to directly access the column name with respect to aliases
    from an unbound column. We have to parse this out from the string representation.

    This works on columns with one or more aliases as well as unaliased columns.

    Returns:
        Col name as str, with respect to aliasing
    """
    c = str(col).removeprefix("Column<'").removesuffix("'>")
    return c.split(' AS ')[-1]
```

Some tests to validate behavior:

```py
import pytest
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def spark() -> SparkSession:
    # Provide a session spark fixture for all tests
    yield SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

def test_get_col_name(spark):
    col = f.col('a')
    actual = get_column_name(col)
    assert actual == 'a'


def test_get_col_name_alias(spark):
    col = f.col('a').alias('b')
    actual = get_column_name(col)
    assert actual == 'b'


def test_get_col_name_multiple_alias(spark):
    col = f.col('a').alias('b').alias('c')
    actual = get_column_name(col)
    assert actual == 'c'


def test_get_col_name_longer(spark: SparkSession):
    """Added this test due to identifying a bug in the old implementation (if you use lstrip/rstrip, this will fail)"""
    col = f.col("local")
    actual = get_column_name(col)
    assert actual == "local"
```

Comment: When the alias contains multiple words separated using spaces, this function returns the column name enclosed in backticks.