# How to recover the column name from an F.col object?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Simple question: 
suppose we

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
```

then how do I recover the column name string 'a' from a pyspark.sql.column.Column object `F.col('a')`.

For example, if we put `str(F.col('a'))`, we have

[image]

rather than the original column name 'a'.

Comment: you can use `df.columns`, `df.schema` or `df.dtypes` only these three properties provide the metadata of the columns

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949579/get-name-alias-of-column-in-pyspark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no supported way of doing this. You can hack things a bit and try something around these lines

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col
from pyspark.sql.column import Column
from py4j.protocol import Py4JError

def name(self):
    try:
        return self._jc.expr().name()
    except Py4JError:
        return None

Column.name = property(name)
```

which would give:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col

col("a").name
```

```
'a'
```

```py
lit(1).name is None
```

```
True
```